# How to send av1 encoded stream to a mediamtx server?

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, gstreamer

I want to test streaming av1 encoded video from the command line but I don't have enough expertise to know if I'm doing something wrong or if it's simply unsupported.

So far I've tried `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! av1enc ! rtspclientsink location=rtsp://localhost:8554/usbcamera` and `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video1 -c:v libsvtav1 -an -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8554/usbcamera`

Using a file source with ffmpeg works with `ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i av1noaudio.mp4 -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:8554/usbcamera` but not with `gstreamer gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=av1noaudio.mp4 ! videoconvert !  rtspclientsink location=rtsp://localhost:8554/usbcamera`

Answer (score 0):

I know ffmpeg does not currently support streaming AV1 to rtp\rtsp.

Any luck doing it with gstreamer?
I tried encoding AV1 files with ffmpeg and then streaming them with gstreamer to mediamtx. Gstreamer seemed find but I keep failing to connect to that path with vlc\ffplay, and so is my rtspsrc to webrtcbin pipeline doesnt show any picture.

I wonder if you have an example of a working thing?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).